# Java SMTP Server classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, smtp

Hello guys i already created a SMTP server mailing I already use the java SMTP mailer jar file and jar file but the error still show.
Do you have any solution for that?

I already made a code for my SMTP server but still the error is showing.!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code and exceptions, post them as code-formatted **text**.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `javax.activation.DataHandeler` class in build classpath, that's why your build is failing. This class is a part of `javax.activation-api`, which [you can find on maven central easily](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0). Just include this jar to build classpath  and you should be good to go. For instance, if you are using Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or using Gradle groovy DSL:

```
implementation 'javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0'
```

Comment: It seems likely that the OP is not using Maven or Gradle, or it would have been pulled in by their JavaMail/JakartaMail dependency.

Comment: Sorry bro amn't using java maven i'm using java ant only this is the lesson that my professsors teach to me and i need to follow that.
Do you have any solution from java ant ? This is the error that show to my code is noclassfoundexception 
Any solution ?

Comment: You're are requesting me to use java maven ?
Is it require ? or do you have any solution to java ant ?

Comment: I'll already try to maven but the errors still showing like that
classnotfoundexception.

Comment: I already put the javax.activation.DataHandler in my class below the package name but the error still appear. 
Can you help me ?
Same problem its classnotfoundexception. i will send you a photo wait.

Comment: Sorry from the inconvenience

Comment: NoClassFoundError Exception

Comment: Sorry guys if i disturb you the error of the program is solve but there's another error here. I'll post that tomorrow.